How can I deal with a helpful, but abrasive, answerer?
tl;dr: What is the suggested way to deal with a helpful, frequent contributor, whose answers are perceived to be phrased in dismissive, abrasive terms?
I'm new to a particular topic, and using a specific Stack Exchange site to ask questions, get answers, and even share new user information that I can't find elsewhere. (I'm intentionally not mentioning the site, because I don't want this to be about my beef with a specific person, but general advice for a not-uncommon pattern.)
One user in particular seems (to me) to be quite knowledgeable, and is quite prolific in their help. However, the answers are—in my opinion—often rude, dismissive of new users not understanding topics that are obvious to this expert.
For example, I recently asked a question (in good faith), the expert answered via a comment. His comment was not a true answer, but made evident what I was missing. I then answered my own question officially with clarity to help future users experiencing the same confusion. The expert made a comment on my answer mocking my question and answer, and (I believe, but don't know) downvoted both question and answer.
I believe this expert is annoyed by my many recent questions (and answers, and comments), and now is biased against me.
How does the community suggest handling situations, in general, where a user is truly helpful, but also rude in their help? Should I:

Ignore the user, ignore the downvotes, and move on?
Flag helpful-but-abrasive comments for mod review?
Clear the air with the expert via discussion in public comments?

If I had a mechanism by which to privately message a user, I'd be happy to reach out and try to have a polite, adult conversation with the expert. I don't have that (and I understand why). I don't think it makes sense to have any discussion about interpersonal matters on a specific question about a technical issue.

Edit: the following background information was previously in the question above, and describes general site-wide behavior. It might be useful towards understanding this user, but is probably irrelevant.

The day-to-day usage on the site seems to be filled with new users (1–100 rep) doing what they usually do: asking often-poor questions, but sometimes not. Signal to noise is low.
There are a few good experts on the site helping out. The help is often not done in a manner I think of as serving the Stack Exchange philosophy. Questions are often answered via comments, instead of answers. The community rarely upvotes questions or answers. Individuals are getting individual help, for sure, but sometimes not in a way that will help future users find the information.


take it to the site's meta? also, you have more than enough rep on the site you're talking about to start a chatroom and invite that user to chat. it wouldn't be a private chatroom, but does that really matter?

Regarding "I believe this expert is annoyed by my many recent questions (and answers, and comments), and now is biased against me. [...] Ignore the user, ignore the downvotes, and move on?": Be more proactive when a user continuously downvotes another user

I disagree with the close votes here. While OP might have a specific incident in mind which is taking place on a specific network site (it would be rather difficult for it to be taking place on more than one!), it seems clear that the appropriate policy (and reasoning behind it) would apply equally network-wide.

I agree with @KarlKnechtel - This question is not specific to one site only. I firmly believe the answers this question is looking for can apply to all (or at the very least more than one) sites.

The question needs more focus. Only one "situación" per post , please.

@Rubén You're right, there's a bunch of superfluous detail on the post. The intention was specifically to ask about how to deal with a single user who is helpful but rude; details about the site's general behavior are unnecessary. I've edited to trim it down.


tl;dr: What is the suggested way to deal with a helpful, frequent contributor, whose answers are perceived to be phrased in dismissive, abrasive terms?

There used to be a line in the code of conduct that said 'assume good intent'. While that's no longer there - it's worth considering. Is that contributor's intent to be dismissive and abrasive, is that how they sound, and most critically are they aware of it?.
A lot of oldschool internet culture is a little rough and ready, so to speak, and they may not be aware of how they come across. 'Fixing' that would need a certain level of understanding and engagement, and even with a good deal of engagement and (hopefully!) respect in the community, I've not always managed to get through in these situations.
I wouldn't say 'grow a thicker skin' - but I'd say focusing on the positives, and assuming good intent is a good way to deal with it on your end.
That said, if someone is being mean, flag appropriately.
Broadly, many of the things you're asking about are signs of a unhealthy community.

There are a few good experts on the site helping out. The help is often not done in a manner I think of as serving the Stack Exchange philosophy. Questions are often answered via comments, instead of answers.

Then they really are not an expert in how to use the site. If a comment or answer was useful, ask them if they could post the comment as an answer, because it was useful and comments are transient.

The community rarely upvotes questions or answers. Individuals are getting individual help, for sure, but sometimes not in a way that will help future users find the information.

That's not really right - but a resolution for this is beyond any one person unfortunately. Solving this is beyond the scope of this answer, or maybe even any one answer. There's all sorts of reasons this could happen - a feeling of eternal September, general unhappiness with initiatives past or presence, or generally just being a jaded.

I recently asked a question (in good faith), the expert answered via a comment. His comment was not a true answer, but made evident what I was missing. I then answered my own question officially with clarity to help future users experiencing the same confusion. The expert made a comment on my answer mocking my question and answer, and (I believe, but don't know) downvoted both question and answer.

I'd flag the comment as unkind. I'd also not assume any specific user downvoted - I often comment instead of downvote (and honestly I really should vote more in general) because it seems a kinder way to try to get someone to improve. As much as reputation 'matters' there's no excuse to mock someone.


whose answers are perceived to be phrased in dismissive, abrasive terms?

Perception depends on the audience, not just the one responsible. If something appears to violate the Code of Conduct, of course that should be flagged. On the other hand, commentary in answers that simply devalues the question (as opposed to berating the OP) is noise that should be edited out.
But that's supposing we're actually talking about answers.

There are a few good experts on the site helping out. The help is often not done in a manner I think of as serving the Stack Exchange philosophy. Questions are often answered via comments, instead of answers.

This is a whole separate issue. It sounds as if the entire site is failing to follow the Stack Exchange model properly, and an intervention is required. You might start by posting on that site's meta.
On the other hand, comments that seem to "answer" the question are often not really an attempt to add an answer to the site. At least on other SE network sites I can think of, they're commonly used:

To explain why a question should be closed (especially if it's a duplicate or a typo: to point out how the problem duplicates the one in the proposed duplicate Q&A, or where the typo is).

To give advice for narrowing down a question, especially on more technical sites like Stack Overflow. For example, a question might "need more focus" because it's expecting others to explain why some dozens of lines of code have some particular problem; someone might comment to describe the process of proper debugging, so that a proper mre can be created. Depending on how the question was phrased, this advice sometimes sounds like an "answer", but is not really intended as such.



The community rarely upvotes questions or answers. Individuals are getting individual help, for sure, but sometimes not in a way that will help future users find the information.

Posting answers (in the answer section) that can "help future users find the information" requires a corresponding question that can help future users. It's the question that will a) generally contain most of the search terms; b) lay out what the problem is, such that future visitors can readily confirm they're in the right place. Answers can't meaningfully make a bad question good, but questions can effectively make good answers bad. (My perspective on this is admittedly somewhat controversial.)
If questions aren't getting upvoted, that could be because nobody is asking good questions that meet the site's standards.
If the people asking those questions are "getting individual help" in the comments, that could be out of a desire to make sure that people don't walk away empty-handed. But posting an answer to a bad question pollutes the site. If nothing else, it interferes with automatic cleanup mechanisms.
There's especially a risk with bad questions that people who are looking for something else stumble on the question - or get their search results polluted with irrelevant "clickbait" questions. No matter how well an answer explains a concept, it's only really "good" if it can be found by the people who need it. Good answer content, therefore, belongs attached to good questions with good SEO. Especially in the case where someone answers a duplicate question before it can be closed as a duplicate - if the answer actually provides any new information, it should be moved (manually, by its author) to the target instead. (And if it doesn't, into the trash bin it goes.)

I then answered my own question officially with clarity to help future users experiencing the same confusion. The expert made a comment on my answer mocking my question and answer, and (I believe, but don't know) downvoted both question and answer.

You indeed don't know and it isn't useful to speculate.
There are two issues to consider here: whether the question meets the site standards (and helps build the site as a repository of information on the topic); and whether the commentary was appropriate.
You can always flag comments for moderator consideration. If they weren't actually unfriendly, they might still be "no longer needed". In my experience, moderators rarely decline such flags. If you have reason to believe the matter is personal (i.e. the expert holds a grudge against you), use a custom flag on any comment, and explain the situation.
If you think the question belongs on the site but the expert seems to disagree, bring it up on the per-site meta.
Please do not use the comment section for any kind of extended discussion. That's not what comments are for. Doing that makes Stack Exchange sites look more like discussion forums, and we Meta regulars try very hard to drill that impression out of people.

From the question

How does the community suggest handling situations, in general, where a user is truly helpful, but also rude in their help? Should I:
Ignore the user, ignore the downvotes, and move on?

Yes.

Flag helpful-but-abrasive comments for mod review?

Yes. Start by flagging one and wait for the mods to handle the flag. You might get a message from the mod handling the flag advising on what to do with similar comments.

Clear the air with the expert via discussion in public comments?

No. Please keep in mind that comments are not meant to do this. If you are thrilled to discuss the behavior with the user in the Stack Exchange realms, invite the user to a specific chat room.
Regarding private messaging the user, this feature is already available for mods and CM. You might flag a comment for moderator review suggesting the mod to do this. If you prefer that a CM do this, use the Contact Us form.
